# Настройки схемы авторизации по токену для SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

Хочу сделать авторизацию через внешний сервис по токену. Подскажите как это сделать, кто с этим уже сталкивался.

**Есть 2 системы:**

1. CRM - основной источник информации по пользователю(в этот сервис и будет отправлять токен через post запрос для получении информации по пользователю)
2. Сам ЧАТ(SignalR) на ASP CORE NET

**Логика:**

1. Клиент находиться на сайте CRM и у него открывается чат
2. При подключении к чату --> со стороны CRM(фронтенда) отправляется token самой CRM в Чат
   Пример:

   ```
       using (var client = new HttpClient())
       {
           string token = Context.GetHttpContext().Request.Query["token"];
           client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Vsaas-Session", token);
           var result = await client.GetAsync($" {Program.DomainServerCrm}/api/chat/user");
           if (result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
           {
               var user = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<User>(await result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync());
               // 1. Проверка пользователя на существование в БД
               var userDb = _context.Users
                   .Include(u => u.Dialogs)
                   .SingleOrDefault(u => u.Id == user.Id);
               if (userDb != null)
               {
                   //При подключении добавляем во все группы этого юзера
                   foreach (var item in userDb.Dialogs)
                   {
                       await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, item.Name);
                   }
                   ChatCollection.ClientConnection[Context.ConnectionId] = userDb;
                   await base.OnConnectedAsync();
               }
           }
       }
   ```
3. На стороне Чата будет использоваться token от CRM для авторизации.

---

Схема БАЗЫ ДАННЫХ ЧАТА:

[image: Схема БАЗЫ ДАННЫХ ЧАТА]

Comment: Вы хотите использовать что-то типа JWT? Если да, то по JWT очень много статей в гугле, если какой-то "свой токен", то гуглите по слову "AuthenticationHandler<T>"

Comment: @LiptonDev для signalR по слову AuthenticationHandler ничего нету. Нашел статью https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2022/01/19/net-6-create-and-validate-jwt-tokens-use-custom-jwt-middleware, нашел статью, но юзера в хабе не смог получить никак

Comment: Через атрибут у класса хаба Authorize с указанием своей собственной схемы авторизации.

Comment: @LiptonDev Есть возможность помочь с кодом за вознагрождение ?

Comment: Telega: ow_dafuq